# Problem installing mysql on 16.04

Tags: mysql

I try to install mysql and I get the following error.  I tried several of the suggestions on the internet with no success.

Thanks,
Y-

```
 See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
odroid@odroid64:~$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up mysql-server-5.7 (5.7.17-0ubuntu0.16.04.2) ...
Renaming removed key_buffer and myisam-recover options (if present)
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2017-03-06 15:44:06 EST; 26ms ago
  Process: 7302 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Mar 06 15:44:06 odroid64 systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
Mar 06 15:44:06 odroid64 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Unit entered failed state.
Mar 06 15:44:06 odroid64 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exi...'.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.7 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.7; however:
  Package mysql-server-5.7 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.7
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```